# MySQL Inner join and subqueries takes a long time

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

I am trying to get a result from the following query but the calculation is taking a very long time

How can I improve it ?

Please help

```
SELECT 
    ic.id, ic.id_number, ia.phone_number 
FROM 
    in_client AS ic 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id_number, MAX(modified) AS modified 
    FROM in_client 
    WHERE 
        id_number IS NOT NULL AND 
        agent_id = 1234
    GROUP BY id_number 
    HAVING MAX(modified) >= '2021-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
) AS max USING (id_number, modified) 
INNER JOIN 
    in_agent AS ia ON (ia.id = ic.agent_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    in_policy AS ip ON (ip.client_id = ic.id) 
WHERE 
    ip.client_id IS NULL
```

SCHEMAS:

**in_client**

```
id - PK (INT)
agent_id - FK (INT)
id_number - VARCHAR
modified - DATETIME
```

**in_agent**

```
id - PK (INT)
name - VARCHAR
```

**in_policy**

```
id - PK (INT)
client_id - FK (INT)
```

*Note: there are more other fields for each table but they are not relevant for this query*

As general IDEA

This query takes all clients from a client table under the same agent who do not have files in the policies table.

Each client can be created multiple times so I used GROUP BY For each group of clients and then I take the most updated client (Modified).

Each client has associated with agent (FK) - so there is an INNER JOIN for perfect match within the sub-querie. And in order to get all clients who do not have files in the policy table, I use LEFT OUTER JOIN

Query Explain:

[image: Query Explain]

Comment: What is this query supposed to do? What are different tables you are using? What is their schema?

Comment: Your description will be clear to understand if you provide the schema for the relevant tables.

Comment: Ok. I did that Thanks

Comment: Can you append the `EXPLAIN` output for that query to the question? ... If one has never run one of these, simply add `EXPLAIN` before the SELECT.

Comment: Please see the screenshot

Comment: Schema in the form of complete `CREATE TABLE` statements (in text, not an image) is best.  Leaving any detail out of a performance question is risky, unless you know the subset schema was tested and produces the same behavior.  Also, show the version of MySQL you're using: `SELECT version();`

Comment: The version is 5.6.0 
And This is Amazon's RDS DB (MySQL)

Comment: MySQL 5.6.0 has been released more than ten years ago. You should consider updating it to a more recent and supported version

Comment: In `in_client`, try adding the following indexes: `INDEX idx1_client (id_number, modified)` and `INDEX idx2_client (agent_id, id_number, modified)`, as a starting point.  I'm not sure 5.5 will make use of both indexes.

Comment: It's tough to guess without the schema.

Comment: @NicoHaase 
Updating the MYSQL engine version is a big change that requires careful sanity testing in all our system..
We work with django and with other frameworks - which require support for advanced engines.
At the moment this is not possible - I'm also not sure I understand how performance is related to a new version

Comment: @JonArmstrong I can't post here the whole table schema

Comment: Just the tables relevant to the question.  The goal is to reduce the amount of guessing involved.  Did you try the indexes?  What was the impact?  Can you edit the question to show the new EXPLAIN result? Lots of performance improvements have been made over the years.  I also wanted to be sure you were using MySQL and not MariaDB.  That's a common mistake in choosing tags for the question.

Comment: @JonArmstrong
Thank you!!
The indexes you said to add solved the problem, The query ran very fast in less than 10 milliseconds!!

If you want you can add this answer as a solution - And I will mark it as a correct answer
if you can please add a short explanation as to why exactly these indexes

Comment: @avimenashe I've updated the answer with detail about these specific indexes.

Comment: @avimenashe I know that updating the database system takes a lot of work. But not doing it for such a long time makes the problem larger from day to day. Plan for upgrades at any time, and plan to do it in way smaller intervals to avoid huge problems on upgrading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `in_client`, try adding the following indexes:

```
  INDEX idx1_client (id_number, modified)
, INDEX idx2_client (agent_id, id_number, modified)
```

These indexes were chosen to satisfy requirements of the query expression inside the `max` derived table, to allow better access to `(agent_id, id_number and modified)` and for the join to in_client `USING (id_number, modified)`.  This was just a first guess without the full schema for these tables.

I used both MariaDB and MySQL for testing, and newer versions to allow creation of the test data dynamically recursively.

The simple test case created to evaluate the problem:

[The fiddle (runs with MariaDB 10.3+ and MySQL 8+)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=85f4e2c2e0f18d11577b2e56ad30f250)

```
CREATE TABLE in_agent (
   id           INT primary key auto_increment
 , name         VARCHAR(30)
 , phone_number varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE in_client (
   id        INT primary key auto_increment
 , agent_id  INT  references in_agent (id)
 , id_number VARCHAR(30)
 , modified  DATETIME DEFAULT current_timestamp
 , INDEX idx1 (id_number, modified)
 , INDEX idx2 (agent_id, id_number, modified)
);

CREATE TABLE in_policy (
   id        INT primary key auto_increment
 , client_id INT references in_client (id)
);

INSERT INTO in_agent (name)
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 (lev) AS (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT lev + 1 FROM cte1 WHERE lev < 100
     )
SELECT CONCAT('name', lev) FROM cte1
;

INSERT INTO in_client (agent_id, id_number)
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 (lev) AS (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT lev + 1 FROM cte1 WHERE lev < 100
     )
SELECT TRUNCATE((lev-1)/50,0)+1, CONCAT('idnum', lev) FROM cte1
;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM in_agent;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM in_client;

SELECT ic.id, ic.id_number, ia.phone_number 
  FROM in_client AS ic 
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_number, MAX(modified) AS modified 
      FROM in_client 
     WHERE id_number IS NOT NULL
       AND agent_id = 1
     GROUP BY id_number 
    HAVING MAX(modified) >= '2021-01-01 01:00:00'
     ) AS max USING (id_number, modified) 
  JOIN      in_agent  AS ia ON (ia.id = ic.agent_id) 
  LEFT JOIN in_policy AS ip ON (ip.client_id = ic.id) 
 WHERE ip.client_id IS NULL
;

EXPLAIN
SELECT ic.id, ic.id_number, ia.phone_number 
  FROM in_client AS ic 
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_number, MAX(modified) AS modified 
      FROM in_client 
     WHERE id_number IS NOT NULL
       AND agent_id = 1
     GROUP BY id_number 
    HAVING MAX(modified) >= '2021-01-01 01:00:00'
     ) AS max USING (id_number, modified) 
  JOIN      in_agent  AS ia ON (ia.id = ic.agent_id) 
  LEFT JOIN in_policy AS ip ON (ip.client_id = ic.id) 
 WHERE ip.client_id IS NULL
;
```

The indexes chosen seem to be better than those in the original question detail.

This should help.